# How to use a table view controller like you would a picker

Tags: ios, swift

I am working on an app right now that how several long UIViewPickers. Instead of the picker I would like to have a table view of all the options.

When you click on a text field it will take you to my table view that lists all the data for that text field.

This is how my table view controller looks right now.

```
  import UIKit

    class SelectOptionsTableViewController: UITableViewController {
    let options = ["New","Used"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of sections
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows
        return options.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "LabelCell", for: indexPath) as! SelectOptionTableViewCell
        cell.selectOptionLabel?.text = options[indexPath.row]
        return cell
    }
}
```

To make the picker come up you would use something like this.

```
   let pickerView = UIPickerView()
    pickerView.delegate  = self
    carTypeTextField.inputView = pickerView
```

If I wanted to make it where I could use SelectOptionsTableViewController instead how would I go about that?

Comment: you can create table and fill data that you need to add in selection option.

now when touch in text field that time table view make visible and when tap in table view cell that time take data from that cell and hide a table view.

Comment: I created the . table with the data in the table view . controller, but I am its not allowing me to use . it as a inputViewController or inputView

Comment: no need to set it as input view when select cell that cell data is taken and set to textfield

Comment: The inputView was how you got the picker to come up when you clicked the a text field, How do I tell the text field to use the table view instead of a picker

Comment: you just need to set table view is hidden false in textview touch begin set selected cell value in text field and hide table view.

Comment: The input and the table view are not on the same view?